# What does 'assignable a, a[*];' mean?

Tags: jml

I've recently read the following JML code in an old exam:

```
Class L {
  /*@non_null*/ int[] a;

  /*@ public normal_behaviour
    @ requires !(\exists int i; 0 <= i && i < a.length; a[i] == d);
    @ ensures a.length == \old(a.length) + 1;
    @ ensures a[\old(a.length)] == d;
    @ ensures (\forall int i; 0 <= i && i < \old(a.length);
                  a[i] == \old(a[i]));
    @ assignable a, a[*];
    @*/
  public void st(int d) {
      ...
  }
}
```

I don't understand the

```
assignable a, a[*];
```

part. What does `a[*]` mean? What would be different if there was only

```
assignable a;
```

?

(A link to a reference would be great.)

Comment: I guess it implies you are allowed to mutate the contents of the array, but that is just a guess :)

Comment: @leppie That was also my guess. But I am not too sure about it, this is why I asked (and this is also the reason why I hope for references).

Comment: You could try violate the assumption (iow, remove `a[*]` as `assignable`) and confirm it fails.

Comment: `a[*]` implies all the indexes in array `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The assignable clause in `JML` only allows a method to modify a location loc if:

```
- loc is mentioned in the method’s assignable clause;
- loc is not allocated when the method starts execution; or
- loc is local to the method (i.e., a local variable or a formal parameter)
```

The use of `a[*]` is shorthand for `[0 ... a.length-1];`[¹](http://www.dc.fi.udc.es/ai/tp/practica/jml/JML/docs/prelimdesign/prelimdesign/prelimdesign_3.html#SEC49)

[More Information](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jml/) | 
[Cited Reference](http://www.dc.fi.udc.es/ai/tp/practica/jml/JML/docs/prelimdesign/prelimdesign/prelimdesign_3.html#SEC49)

Comment: Just to clarify: "assignable a, a[*]" means that you both may do "a = new int[0];" and "a[17] = 42", whereas by omitting one sub-clause the respective statement would be illegal.

I'd vote for choosing that answer as the right one, by the way.